# Force PDF download in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I saved a pdf in my server and I am trying to force download when user click on a button. The pdf is downloaded but I am unable to view the pdf in Adobe Reader because there are html codes of the page user was in before "%pdf."

View-report.php:

```
<form name="reports" method="post" class="reports" >    
    <table name= "report" class="report">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>column heading</td>
                <td>column heading</td>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>cell data</td>
                <td>cell data</td>  
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="downloadPDF_button" name="savePDF" formtarget="_blank">Save PDF</button>
</form> 

<?php
if (isset($_POST['savePDF'])) {
    $urlname = 'http://sitename.com/uploads/test/report.pdf';

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($urlname);
    exit();
}
?>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Why do you call `flush()`?

Comment: @csabinho sorry, was trying out some suggestions which use flush() but it doesnt work.

Comment: Have you already tried it without it? `ob_clean()` should have cleaned your output buffer. And also: what's the HTML that is printed before your PDF? And do you use`ob_start()`? Output buffering most probably won't work without the typical output buffering functions!

Comment: @csabinho I tried removing flush() and adding ob_start() before "header('Content-type: application/pdf');" but it doesn't work. The html printed includes the html from View-report.php, something like this "<html><head>all scripts</head><body><form><table>all table contents</table><button name="savePDF">Save PDF</button></form> %pdf"